# Hide some POI in Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found a way to hide all business poi in Google Maps. And it works great.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I just want to hide some POI categories like restaurants or bars. How can I do that?
[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types) I found a list of category types but it doesn't work when I try it like this.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi.restaurant",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly you can't hide poi.buisness by sector. According to the documentation relative to [style-features](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#style-features) of the `style-reference` you can choose to hide some poi by type

- `poi.attraction` selects tourist attractions.
- `poi.business` selects businesses.
- `poi.government` selects government buildings.
- `poi.medical` selects emergency services, including hospitals, pharmacies, police, doctors, and others.
- `poi.park` selects parks.
- `poi.place_of_worship` selects places of worship, including churches, temples, mosques, and others.
- `poi.school` selects schools.
- `poi.sports_complex` selects sports complexes.